# sed regular expression using ' sign in ubuntu

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I wish to use `sed` in ubuntu to replace a row in a file `file.txt`.

my row starts with a certain pattern `foo` followed by any number of any characters. I wish to replace this with `foo='x'`. I was trying to use the following command from bash:

`sed -i 's/^foo*/foo='x'/g' file.txt`

Obviously the `'` symbol brakes the string transferred to `sed`. Moreover, the regular expressions don't sim to work for me when I remove the problematic symbol. I simply replace only the pattern `foo` and not the whole row.

For example the original `file.txt`:

> foo='bla'

The requested result `file.txt`:

> foo='SomethingElse'

I tried a number of variables such as: `sed -i 's/\^foo\*/foo=\'x\'/g' file.txt` to no avail. I could not find information on the subject online though I am sure this is not the first time someone encountered this problem.

How do I use `'` in the target (or the pattern I am searching for that matter)?
And what is up with the regex in this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed

```
sed "/foo/s/='.*'/='1234'/g" file
foo='1234'
```

This search for `foo`, then replace `='` with `='1234` on that line.

When you have `'` int your text, change start and stop of sed to `"`

Another variation using back reference and `-E`

```
sed -E "s/(foo=').*/\11234'/g" file
foo='1234'
```

If you like to use single quote, you have to get out of sed with single quote and then escape the single quote and then a new single quote to get in to sed like this messy solution:

```
sed '/foo/s/='\''.*/='\''1234'\''/g' file
```

or hex code it:

```
sed '/foo/s/=\x27.*\x27/=\x271234\x27/g' file
```

Comment: This leaves me with the `bla` pattern in the tail. what if I want to replace it?

Comment: @havakok updated post with new example